# Throw a die 6 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Lets assume that we throw a die 6 times and we want that die to have a value greater than 3  exactly 3 times.

Looking at the question , intuitively  I would say the probability is 1/2.

But doing calculations It does not seem that way :

number of total cases : $6^6$ (have 6 value from 1 to 6 and throwing the die 6 times)

number of the wanted cases : C(6,3).$3^3$.$3^3$   (first chose 3 places from 6 and each 6 places has 3 values it is either 4,5,6 or 1,2,3 )

dividing the number of wanted cases to total cases I get 5/16 .

What is wrong ? my intuition or  the way I calculate ?

Comment: I really do not understand why this question was downvoted.

Comment: @drhab neither did  I ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong.

In order to see that suppose that your intuition is correct.

Then the probability on exactly $1000$ heads by throwing $2000$ fair coins should equal $0.5$.

Do you still trust your intuition?...

Comment: Yeah , you are right .My  intuition was wrong. I got the point thanks :)

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to consider values 1,2,3 ans 4,5,6 separately, as half of the terms are greater than 3 and the other half are not. So you can consider 1,2,3 as p and 4,5,6 as q, being single terms. Considering p and q as the only possible outcomes, the total possible outcomes are $2^6$ instead of $6^6$. Now, to chooses 3 out of 6 die, you can simply use $6\choose3$ to get 20 combinations. Now your final answer will be $\frac{20}{64}=\frac{5}{16}$. So your answer was correct, which means your intuition was wrong.